# Timing Belt Replacement Schedule on 2004 KIA

Tags: engine, scheduled-maintenance, kia, timing-belt

Can anyone tell me at what recommended mileage should the timing belt be replaced on a 2004 KIA 4 clylinder engine.  And if you know, is this a job for a pro or can a do it yourself person do it?  thanks.

Comment: Isn't this in your owner's manual? I worry that this question is too simple and general for a site aimed at professionals. See this meta page for more:

http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/3/making-a-site-for-professionals

Answer (score 1):

> A: The service manual shows that the belt is to be replaced at 60,000 miles or 100,000 km. On both the 2.4 and 2.7 liter motors. So you still got some miles to put on your car. Happy motoring

Source:  http://kiacarsfaq.com/Kia+Optima/2004+Kia+Optima.html

---

> make sure you replace the timing belt every 50K-60K miles, as they have an 'interference' motor, so if your belt breaks on you, it'll be cheaper to buy an entirely new engine rather than fix your broken one.

Source:  http://repairpal.com/kia-optima-2004

I would suggest obtaining the actual service manual.  I don't know how accurate this information is as it's not official.